Regex replacing blanks with `_` and removing all from a special symbol
Given a string, I want to remove all of the string from one of the symbols ., ? and : (so the output string does contain neither the symbol nor what follows it) and I want to replace all blanks with underscores.
I am trying the next code, but it does not work.
// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler

var str = "Some text .$0 oaisy9";

function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  var str2 = string.replace(p2, '')
  return str2.replace(p1, '_');
}


console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("(\s+)|([:?.].*$)","g"), replacer));

I get Some text Some text  while I would expect Some_text_.
How should I define replacer or modify the RegExp?
Thanks!

how is p1 is non-digits or p2 digits ??? and as for p3 non-alphanumerics - there is no p3

You're close. Just replace one at a time to make it simple. "Some text .$0 oaisy9".replace(/[:?.].*/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '_')

with that replacer function, you would do if (p1) { return '_'; } return ''; - of course, you need to do console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("(\\s+)|([:?.].*$)","g"), replacer)); - the double \ is important when using new RegExp with a string argument

@JaromandaX Regarding your first comment, an error on my side due to copy and paste from a previous example. Regarding your secind comment, thank you very much both for the answer and the regex fix

I think your regExp is correct, but need to update replace function.
function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  if (p2) {
    // If there's a match for the second capturing group (the symbol followed by the rest of the string)
    return '';
  }
  if (p1) {
    // If there's a match for the first capturing group (whitespace)
    return '_';
  }
  return match;
}


Your regExp has two group - (\s+), and ([:?.].*$), In updated replacer function parameter p1 for first and parameter p2 for second.
if p1 is mached, return empty string, and if p2 is mached, return underscore. otherwise return original match string.
So you can get your expected result.

You can simplify function replacer like this:


function replacer(text, rem, srch, repl) {
  return text.replace(rem, '').replace(srch, repl);
}

var str = "Some text .$0 oaisy9";

console.log(replacer(str, /[.?:].*/, / /g, '_'));
//=> Some_text_



We have 2 replace invocations in the function:

1st replace removes text based on regex supplied in argument rem
2nd replace replaces regex matched by argument srch with repl

